# Hiding cell in static table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've got a static table view in IB with outlets type of UITableViewCell for each cell. I am trying to hide a particular cell by setting 0 height. I am using `indexPathForCell` of given outlet. The problem is that `indexPathForCell` returns nil. Here is the code:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath compare:[tableView indexPathForCell:self.cellSelfView]] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

The only solution I know is comparing `indexPath.row` with particular index, but that solution is not reliable. Any ideas of hiding cell are appreciated.

Comment: If you are using outlets you don't need index paths because you can address each cell directly.

Comment: But how to set height in that case? heightAnchor doesn't work and rowHeight works only for table view

Comment: Have you tried an `NSLayoutConstraint` outlet?

Comment: I've tried now, but couldn't place it for table view cell

Comment: I recommend to do this in `willDisplayCell`. Do your check there and set your `cell.frame` accordingly.

Comment: @koen Do you mean 'cell.frame.size.height'?  If yes, there is an error "Expression is not assignable"

Comment: Try this: `cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 0.0f);` for zero height cells.

Answer (score 0):

I find the delegate method `willDisplayCell` to be the most suitable place to make last minute visual changes just before a cell is shown.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    if indexPath.row == // do your check here to see if the cell should be hidden {
       cell.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.size.width, 0.0); // set a zero height to hide the cell
    }
}
```